# 3rd normal form with unique values

Tags: database, relational-database, third-normal-form

I have table `USER` with schema `USER(user_id, email, first_name, last_name, ...)`.
Email is a unique value in my database, user_id is a primary key. So, user_id and email are candidate keys.
Does it mean that I have a transitive dependency here (`user_id -> email -> (first_name, last_name, ...)`) and thus the database is not in NF3?

Comment: What is your 1 clear question? If it is whether a certain FD is transitive, what FD do you mean & where are you stuck applying the definition to it? PS Your multiple unclear questions involve whether conclusions are right but you only give vague fragments of definitions & reasoning. You are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work. Quote & use definitions, show all steps of reasoning & ask 1 specific question re the first place you are stuck. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: You probably meant *the table is not in 3NF*, not *the database*, and *email is a unique column in the table*, not *unique value in my database*. Because a database is more than a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting the `Relational Database` tag.

The main problem, that confuses everything, is that there is one Relational Model, and then various nonsense that is promoted by others as "relational".

1. The one and only original **Relational Model** by Dr E F Codd.

- This is a rock-solid definition that has not changed since June 1970, and does not need to change.  Truth is permanent, it does not change.  It is the basis upon which the commercial platform providers *can* build their platforms, and have done so in the 1980's.

2. The Date & Darwen & Fagin version, which is the **Record Filing Systems** of the 1960's, pre-database as well as pre-Relational: the very thing that the *RM* replaces.  Plus a couple of fragments (not whole concepts) from the *Relational Model*.  Promoted and marketed heavily as "relational", which is not correct.

- This is a collection of fragments, that is forever changing.  They are now up to several "relational algebras"; 17 abnormal "normal forms" (they have changed the original Normal Forms to suit their own purposes); etc.
- The following terms do not exist in the *Relational Model*, they are terms used to elevate the fragments in their RFS to obtain a little bit of relational appearance.

  - "transitive dependence"
  - "candidate keys"
- 1960's RFS are characterised by a `Record ID` (yours is `user_id`), which is a physical (not logical) pointer.  This is expressly prohibited in the *RM*, which is logical, and breaks away from the pointer-based systems that preceded it.
- The central difference (not the only difference) between the 1960's RFS and the *RM* is, whereas the RFS the relates physical record using physical pointers such as `Record ID`, the *RM* relates logical rows of data (not records) using natural Keys that occur in the data.
- The non-commercial platform providers that arose in the 1990's typically make reference to these additions, or supply provisions that are prohibited in the *RM*, and sometimes provide features to ease the pain caused by them.

The **[Relational Model](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Codd%20E%20F/A%20Relational%20Model%20of%20Data%20for%20Large%20Shared%20Data%20Banks.pdf)** is freely available (in those days, only qualified people attempted database design).  However, the terms are dated and thus not understood today.  And it is seminal, dense.  The proponents count on that, in order to promote their approach as "relational".

---

### The Relational Model

I will answer for the *Relational Model*.  In order to avoid going over the same item more than once, I will take the issues in logical sequence.

1. The *RM* requires that each row (not record, because it is beyond records) is unique.
2. In the *RM*, one or more Unique Keys are selected for each table.  Each Key must be "made up from the data".  Further, each Key must be non-redundant, the minimal Key.  If there is more than one Key, one is chosen as **Primary Key**, which is migrated to the subordinate rows as a Foreign Key.  Once the Primary Key is chosen, any Keys that remain are **Alternate Keys**.

> While the Keys may be loosely called "candidates" before the election, after the election they are no longer "candidates", they are losers.
>
> - The use of the term "candidate" serves only to (a) maintain the tension of not choosing a Primary Key from one of the "candidates" (as required by the *RM*), and (b) thus allow a non-Key (such as a fabricated `Record ID` or `user_id` as a `PRIMARY KEY`.
> - A `Record ID` field does not exist in the data, it is manufactured by the system (`GUID; AUTO INCREMENT`; etc).  Such a field is great for perceiving the data in physical terms (RFS), as if it were a stupefying grid, and therefore suppressing the perception of data as logical components the are related (the *RM*).
> - A genuine Key has many important properties.  Declaring a non-Key to be a `PRIMARY KEY`, which is possible in SQL, does not magically give the non-Key any of those properties.

- Therefore the schema is `USER(`<strike>`user_id,`</strike> `email, first_name, last_name, ...)`

3. You have recognised that `email` is an unique identifier.  Great.  In fact, for that schema, it is the only Key, so you do not have to concern yourself with choosing one from many possibles.

Here is a comparison.

[image: BakTA]

- All my data models are rendered in **[IDEF1X](https://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)**, the Standard for modelling Relational databases since 1993.
- My **[IDEF1X Introduction](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Introduction.pdf)** is essential reading for beginners.

---

Now you want to check if the table satisfies 3NF. Dmitry's intention is correct, although his definition might not be.  Dr E F Codd's 3NF, not the pretenders:

- **A row is in third normal form iff every non-prime attribute is Functionally Dependent on the Key, the whole Key, and nothing but the Key.**
- The *RM* has only "full" Functional Dependence, it does not assist those who fragment the Key to deal with their fragments.
- Transitivity is a logical and mathematical term, it is not subtracted in the *RM*, rather, it simply does not apply, it is not required, because it deals with the whole Key, whereas RFS deals with fragments of the Key.
- `first_name, last_name, ...`
  are each Functionally Dependent on `email`, and nothing but `email`.
- Therefore it satisfies 3NF.

---

### 1960's Record Filing System

Sorry, I can't help you there, because it is an ever-changing and unreliable mess that deals with fragments of data instead of recognising the atoms, and they will argue endlessly, resolving nothing.  They work on notions that are not in the *RM*, and therefore fraudulently called "relational", while retaining the essential parts of the 1960's Record-oriented paradigm: the additional field and additional index for the physical `Record ID`; and the reference by physical `Record ID`.  Both of which are prohibited by the *RM*.

---

## Comments

<sub>This section is presented in accordance with the SO guidelines, specifically: **to correct misinformation whenever you see it**. I did respond to the comments, but they keep disappearing. Thus I have placed it here.</sub>

> *philipxy:
>
> Codd's 1971 [paper] "Further normalization of the data base relational model" introduced "normalization" in the sense of decomposition to higher NFs, including "FD", "CK", "one of its CKs is arbitrarily designated as PK", "2NF" in terms of "partial/full FDs" & "3NF" in terms of "transitive/non-transitive FDs".*

1. That quote is from the 1971 paper, not the Jun 1970 paper **[The Relational Model](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Codd%20E%20F/A%20Relational%20Model%20of%20Data%20for%20Large%20Shared%20Data%20Banks.pdf)**.  They are two different papers.  Therefore it is confirmed:

- that that content is in the 1971 paper
- the Jun 1970 *Relational Model* paper does not have that content.

as such, **the 1971 paper can be dismissed**.

2. As evidenced, Codd wrote about twelve additional papers during the decade (1970 to 1980) that he was trying to get the *RM* accepted.  They have no value except for historical purposes, to examine the way he responded to the upheaval of the DBMS platform suppliers, that was caused by the *RM*: it was a paradigm shift.

The 1971 paper, and the "RM/Tasmania" articles and presentations, have the explicit purpose of assisting the then entrenched DBMS platform users to implement a bit of relational capability into their systems without changing the platform, the reference-by-physical-pointer paradigm (mindset & implementation).

> After the *Relational Model* became accepted, around 1985, when all the DBMS platform suppliers started switching to supplying RDBMS platforms, ie. the reference-by-physical-pointer platforms became extinct, the 1971 paper, which was *previously* near and dear to them, became obsolete.

Therefore, again, **the 1971 paper can be dismissed**.

3. The only article (not a formal paper, but widely accepted as one) that is relevant to the *RM* is the 1985 ComputerWorld article commonly known as **Codd's Twelve Rules**, which gives the rules for both (a) a DBMS Platform, and (b) a database, to be accepted as genuinely Relational.  That was to overcome the problem of DBMS platform suppliers adding Relational bits and pieces and then labelling their product "relational".
4. Still confused? A scientific person would:

- recognise that the *RM* contradicts the 1971 paper, and the 1971 paper contradicts the *RM*,
- recognise that they cannot both be true at the same time,
- apply the **Law of Non-Contradiction**,
- and **cancel the 1971 paper**.

5. The Date, Darwen, Fagin, et al, and all their followers (authors, professors, lecturers, etc), are not stupid.  Therefore the following evidence acts:

- the non-resolution of the purported issue [4],
- the suppression of the *RM* (atomicity; Codd's three NFs unchanged; the Relational Key; "full" Functional Dependence on the Relational Key),
- the elevation of the obsolete 1971 paper (fragmentation; ever-changing re-definitions of 17 NFs; physical `RecordID` as "key"; partial FDs to deal with the fragments; etc),
- the declaration that the 1971 paper, that was obsolete as of 1985, that contradicts the *Relational Model*, is "the relational model".  As evidenced by philipxy and others.

are incorrect, and are in disagreement with the original relational model.

#### Institutionalised Suppression of the *Relational Model*

It is reinforced by additional acts:

- misrepresenting Codd's Rule 1 (the *after the fact* View of data from the database) as the definitive, *before the fact* perception of data, and that that is the "table":

> *Erwin Snout:
>
> When cut down to its bare essence, the relational model of data has no more than exactly one "rule" : all information in the database must be represented as values of attributes in tuples in relations.*

There are over 40 rules in the *Relational Model* and the *Twelve Rules*.  Reducing them to one pithy rule is not compatible with the *RM*.

- which eliminates the possibility of genuine data modelling
- perpetuating the use of the totally obsolete **ERD** for data analysis & modelling, which does not support the central article of the *Relational Model*, the composite Relational Key, and thus maintains the perception of fragments
- suppressing the use of **IDEF1X**, which is designed for the *Relational Model*, available since 1985, the NIST Standard for modelling Relational data since 1993.  It formalises the concepts in the *RM*.

Comment: @BakhanovA.  [This Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59155083/484814) might interest you.

Answer (score 0):

3NF definition [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) that

> "All the **non-prime** attributes must depend only on the candidate keys."

If you have two candidate keys then they naturally define all other attributes, that's okay. The point of 3NF is that there is no FD with **non-keys** on both sides.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a definition saying something, but that quote is not stating a condition necessary for 3NF. That statement from the linked article is wrong. (Wikipedia relational model articles are full of misconceptions & errors.) There's something similar that it's presumably trying to say, but it's not saying it. And it's not clear what you mean by "the point of" a NF or 3NF, but "there is no FD with non-keys on both sides" is not a characterization or consequence of 3NF. Also you don't clearly connect what you write to the (unclear) questions in the post.

Comment: @philipxy Okay. Is Jeffrey Ullman's definition good enough? It says: *“for each nontrivial FD, either the left side is a superkey, or the right side consists of prime attributes only."*

The question in post is pretty clear to me, it asks *"is it true that transitive FD user_id -> email -> (any other non-key attribute) violates 3NF?"*

The answer: no, it doesn't, because in all FDs which we're aware of in this table there is a key on the left side.

Comment: Ullman's definition & relevant reasoning belong in your answer. Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS "Pretty clear" here is a euphemism for a case of "not clear". x->y->z is not a FD. user_id -> (first_name, last_name, ...) is not transitive. The question doesn't say that the only FDs that hold are the ones implied by those 2 CKs. Also the asker was following some line of argument & what they most likely want to know is what was wrong with it & your comment doesn't address that--typical of answers to unclear questions.